# Missing Controller when read upload file in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I have created folder(upload) in main cake directory(cakephp 3.0) and upload file in this folder. when i read and get content of this file then cake php throw error "Missing Controller".

my upload file url :- http://localhost/newoce/xyz/upload/CaptionSync__Sample.vtt
Cake dir structure:-
bin
config
**upload**
logs
src
vendor
webroot

my requirement is that upload all files in upload folder not in webroot folder and read files from upload folder.

Can any help me how we read file from upload folder.

Thanks
Ramesh

Comment: Please can you share your current code ?

Comment: my code
$url = 'http://localhost/newoce/xyz/upload/CaptionSync__Sample.vtt ';
$curl = $this->getCurl();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
echo $captions = curl_exec($curl); die;

Comment: i get file content by curl

Comment: so are you able to open file direct in browser with link  http://localhost/newoce/xyz/upload/CaptionSync__Sample.vtt ???

Comment: no. show Object not found!

Comment: then definitely your url path is not well, what is newoce ? and xyz ? and where is upload located ?

Comment: in newoce cakephp folder and other custom folder and file. and in xyz all cakephp folder and file

Comment: in xyz folder we create upload folder and upload all file. its working fine. but when we read file from upload folder then show error.

Comment: Its very difficult to understand, let me try one thing that please move upload folder above the xyz folder and inside the newoce

Comment: if i move upload folder above xyz folder and inside webroot then its working fine. but i want in xyz folder with cake folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create .htaccess file in upload directory and put following code in that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /upload/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /upload/ [L]
</IfModule>
```